# How can I tell angularjs to stop watching a variable for a while?

Tags: angularjs

I am updating a long array, that has complex calculation and can take a second or two.

While the array is changing ( i.e. in different algorithm steps ), angular keep updating the ui for each intermediate steps.

How do I ask angular to stop looking for change for this variable for a second or two and start watching it again after I complete ?

Comment: try hiding the part of UI until all the steps are complete by introducing a new $scope variable and `ng-show`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I ask angular to stop looking for change for this variable for
>   a second or two and start watching it again after I complete ?

Assuming you are referring to the 2 way data binding between a controller scope variable and the view, one solution would be to do the calculations off the scope in a controller variable and then assign that variable to the scope afterward. This way during the "second or two" that the calculations are taking place, the digest cycle wouldn't be triggered on variable:

```
// making copy so we are not passing by reference (array or object)    
var localCopyOfVar = angular.copy( $scope.complexArray ); 

// do complex stuff with localCopyOfVar
// ...

// assign finished work back onto scope variable    
$scope.complexArray = localCopyofVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `{{ }}` in the HTML markup you cannot stop the watches. If you created the $watch yourself you can stop it and restart is later like this:

```
var watchFunction = ... blahBlah ...
var stopWatch = scope.$watch('foo', watchFunction)

stopWatch()
```

You can minimize / eliminate the screen flicker by doing all of the updates within a single digest by not using $timeouts.